# listing processes and their connections

Tags: windows, process, internet-connection

I would like to make a small program listing running programs on my
computer - this seems simple. But I would also like to detect their
connections, ex.: I detect a running Internet Explorer (or other
browser), but I would like to know which websites it is visiting.
Another example; I detect Word is running, and would like to know what
document(s) it is working with. Is it possible to query the http-
protocol to discover online connections? And how about programs that
open local resources? So, listing running programs and their
connections is what I want to do - and do I have to poll for it every minute or is
there better ways of watching these processes?

It must be able to run on MS Windows, but the programminglanguage is not important

Thanx

Ask

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider some of the pre-existing tools capable of doing this.  Both Windows NT and most Unixes come with the "netstat" command.

Windows NT: netstat -b

Unix: netstat -p

Comment: right... But I need to format it nicely since it will be shown to "normal" people. Thus a list of ip-numbers, ports and apps wont be enough. But programs and their connections can be fetched from the "netstat"? Sounds good. How about what documents are open in i.e. MSWord?

Comment: Ah, yes.  If you're interested in more than just network connections, then netstat won't do it.  Try Peter's suggestion of Process Monitor.  If your concerned about nice formatting, you might see if it can export data in the format you require; but I think it can do most of what you want and might save you from reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I like using Process Monitor. Find it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx